# Internal Error Sql140DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid while publishing website with SQL Server 2017 database to web server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017

I have a VPS web server with SQL Server 2017 Web edition (v14.0.3257.3) with the latest updates installed.

I use Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2017 Express (v14.0.3257.3) with the latest updates installed to publish a website with a SQL Server database.

I get this error:

> Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql140DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.

Two days I search for a solution on Google and Stackoverflow but I can't find anything to fix my problem.

On my development machine I installed the latest versions of SMSS and SSDT.

Who can help my in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the exact same issue today. To resolve this, I installed `DACFramwork.msi` from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15).

And, instead of looking for `SqlPackage.exe` in the *Program Files x86*, I looked for the same inside *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin*.

Not fully sure as to how it works, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, and I do this on my workstation or on my server?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. Probably your issue would have got resolved by now. However, just to answer this point; it is in your workstation and not in the server.

Comment: Hi, oke. I installed DACFramwork, but I publish with Visual Studio and I don't know where VS looks for programs to use. But after installing DACFramwork I still get the same error message.